# How to PUT to specific Index of an Array in a JSON string, REST-API?

Tags: json, api, rest

When workinging with a REST API, How would I send a JSON string that specifies to PUT to index [0] of the shop array? Is this possible within a JSON string?

This is not a question on how to select an array index in Javascript.

```
{
    "Shops": {
        "Shop": [
            {
                ...stuff
                "reorderLevel": "3" // Put to index [0] of the Shop array?
            },
            {
                ...stuff
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe by passing another parameter within your json string?

Comment: I guess it depends on the API, I just wondered if there was a more generic way to specify an array index within the string.

Comment: But, you are doing it in the first position, so I guess your API will do it that 0 position.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but no.

Comment: Do you have access to your API code?

Comment: I guess your API should have that behavior implemented in the code; if you have access to it then take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I guess this is a dead end

Comment: What happens if you send it that way?

Comment: Can you implement the process in the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When workinging with a REST API, How would I send a JSON string that specifies to PUT to index [0] of the shop array?

You would do one of the following things

Using PUT, you would create a new representation of the *entire* resource with the changes you wanted to make, and then send the whole thing in a single request to the server

or

You would compute a patch-document, that describes only the changes that you wanted to make to the document, and then send a PATCH request to the server with a representation of your changes.

[application/merge-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) and [application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) are the two most common formats.

Merge-patch, as far as I can tell, does not support references to individual elements of an array:

> If the patch is anything other than an object, the result will always be to replace the entire target with the entire patch.

JSON-patch uses [JSON pointers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) to specify elements, and there is a JSON pointer syntax for a specific array element, so you should be able to make that work.